# How to Analytically Solve this PDE?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations

Thanks for looking at my question. I'm working through/self-studying the second edition of Partial Differential Equations: An Introduction by Walter A. Strauss.

On page three, example two, he says

"Solve the PDE $u_{xx} + u = 0$. Again, its really an ODE with an extra variable y. We know how to solve the ODE, so the solution is $u = f(y)cos(x) + g(y)sin(x)$, where again $f(y)$ and $g(y)$ are two arbitrary functions of $y$. You can easily check this formula by differentiating twice to verify that $u_{xx} = -u$."

What I don't understand is how he gets $u = f(y)cos(x) + g(y)sin(x)$.

He says it's basically just an ODE with an extra variable y, but I'm not quite seeing that. I was able to understand Example 1 before it and Example 3 after it, and I can sort of see that this PDE is similar to the ODE form $y'' + y = 0$, but it's just been a hot minute since I've solved an ODE like this. I see it's homogenous, and one could use the method of integrating factors for it, but since this is a PDE I'm not sure how to solve this. My initial guess of $C_{1}e^{r_{1}t} + C_{2}e^{{r_2}t}$ didn't work, so I'm not sure how they got what they got for $u$. I get that when you integrate with respect to $x$ the constant you get is a function of $y$, but that's all I understand about this problem. Could someone show me how Walter got his solution for $u$, please? Thanks.

Comment: You're usually given boundary conditions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We want to solve $\frac{\partial^2}{\partial x^2} u(x,y)+u(x,y)=0.$ As you said, we can solve this like an ODE. Let us consider a guess $u(x,y)=c(y)e^{rx}.$ We make $c$ depend on $y$ because $c(y)$ is still constant in $x$, which is the variable that we're differentiating in. Plugging in such a guess, we get the characteristic equation
$$r^2+1=0,$$ which has imaginary roots at $\pm i$, which yields the solution 
$$u(x,y)=c(y)\cos x+b(y)\sin x.$$ So, the mistakes in your interpretation were that your guess should depend on $y$ and that your guess was a perfectly valid one, but you must consider complex roots here.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, it is definitely helpful and nicely written. This is a dumb question, but I get where the $r^2$ comes from, but why do you keep the $r$ term? Shouldn't that correspond to the first derivative of a function? Something like $y'' + y' = 0$? Why is it not some constant term, like $a$? Wait, would it correspond to $1$ which creates the complex roots $+i$ and $-i$ which is where the solution comes from? Is that it?

Comment: I made a typo, fixed!

Comment: Ah, I see it now, yeah, makes sense now. Is there a way to solve for $c(y)$ and $b(y)$ or would we need initial conditions for those? I was just thinking of Euler's formula which looks similar to the solution here.

Comment: You're correct, we need (boundary) condition to find our coefficients. As for Euler's formula, this is what allows us to get from our solution $c(y)e^{rx}$, with $r$ imaginary, to solutions of the form of $\sin x$ and $\cos x$.

Answer (score 5):

Fix an arbitrary value for $y$, say $y_0$. Then let $f(x) =u(x,y_0)$. You can immediately see that $f''+f=0$. This is very common ODE and most people just know that $\sin$ and $\cos$ are solutions, but if you're unhappy with that you can get there with $\exp(\omega x)$ solutions and some algebra.

Now we know that $f(x) = A \sin(x) + B \cos(x)$ for an arbitrary $y_0$. The only thing that can change when we change $y_0$ are the values of constants $A,B$.

This finally leads to conclusion $u(x,y) = A(y)\sin(x) + B(y)\cos(x)$ and the $A,B$ now functions of $y$ are determined by boundary conditions.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I can see it now.

Answer (score 4):

There are a few facts that are always treated as "obvious" in ODEs (because, presumably, you've been thinking about them non-stop since Calc I):

- The derivative of a constant (with respect to any independent variable) is zero.
- The derivative of a polynomial (with respect to its variable) reduces the degree by one.
- The derivative of $f(x) = \mathrm{e}^{kx}$ with respect to $x$ is a constant multiple of $f$.  (Precisely, $\dfrac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x} \mathrm{e}^{kx} = k \mathrm{e}^{kx}$.)
- The *second* derivatives of $g(x) = \sin kx$ and $h(x) = \cos kx$ with respect to $x$ are constant multiples of $g$ and $h$, respectively.  (Precisely, $\dfrac{\mathrm{d}^2}{\mathrm{d}x^2} \sin kx = -k^2 \sin x$, and similarly for cosine.)  Additionally, odd order derivatives of $g$ and $h$ swap them.

So, when you see "the second derivative of $y$ is the negative of $y$", you should be thinking "sine and cosine" pretty much immediately.

The bullet point about sine and cosine can be rolled into the one about exponentials, so you *could* have gotten there with your characteristic equation method, but you need to recall what exponentiation does to complex numbers.  In particular, you recall $\mathrm{e}^{\mathrm{i}x} = \cos x  + \mathrm{i} \sin x$.  So what would happen with your characteristic equation is, from
$$  y'' + y = 0 $$
you have the characteristic equation
$$  x^2 + 1 = 0  \text{.}  $$
Then the characteristic roots are $\pm \mathrm{i}$, so the solutions (with arbitrary constants $c_1$ and $c_2$) are $c_1 \mathrm{e}^{\mathrm{i} x}$ and $c_2 \mathrm{e}^{-\mathrm{i} x}$.  These are sines and cosines in disguise:  \begin{align*}
\mathrm{e}^{\mathrm{i} x} &= \cos x + \mathrm{i} \sin x  \\
\mathrm{e}^{-\mathrm{i} x} &= \cos x - \mathrm{i} \sin x  \text{.}
\end{align*}

Comment: Ahh, yes, thanks for the answer. I appreciate the thoroughness and how well written it is. Yeah, those facts are definitely at play here. It all makes sense now though.